# How to compare EditText1 of MainActivity with EditText2 of SecondActivity (SharedPreferences)?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, sharedpreferences

I have 2 EditTexts. EditText1 is in MainActivity, EditText2 is in SecondActivity.
EditText1 is to login (password), EditText2 is to change password.

My code looks like this:

```
EditText editText1 = findViewById(R.id.login);
         editText2 = findViewById(R.id.changePassword); // declared in SecondActivity

if (editText1.getText().toString().equals(editText2.getText().toString())
{
  Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
  startActivity(intent);
}
else
{
  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Password incorrect", Toast.Length_Long).show;
}
```

When I press Button to login, it shows me an error. I know it has to be initialized in a different way but how?

I tried another code with a Dialog and everything worked perfectly:

```
changePasswordDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
changePasswordDialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_activity);

editText2 = changePasswordDialog.findViewById(R.id.changePassword);
```

So it works perfectly with Dialog, but how does it work without Dialog?

Comment: You can't reference UI elements from one activity in another activity.  The typical way you would do this would be to pass the EditText text from the first activity to the second activity using an Intent.  You could also use shared preferences here, but you might not have to.

Comment: Your editext2 will throw null pointer exception too as findviewbyId will be null in this case

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I use shared preferences, but I didn't know I can compare it with shared preferences. My code looks like this: SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myShPref", 0);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                        editor.putString("key1", editText2.getText().toString());
                        editor.apply();

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this
*Store edit text 2 pass*

```
    String pass = editText2.getText().toString().trim();
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(My_Prefs,Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

editor.putString("pass", pass);
editor.apply();
```

*Now Retrive the stored passwod in MainActivity*

```
SharedPrefrences prefrences = getSharedPrefrences(My_Prefs,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String pass = prefrences.getString("pass","");
if (editText1.getText().toString().equals(pass)
{
  Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: " String pass = preferences.getString("pass", ""); " ... Why is the defValue ""?

Comment: keep it blank.It means return default String

Answer (score 0):

You can use intent put extra and intent get extra for this

/// you can use this as per your requirement or you can use sharedprefrence///

// In main activity ///

```
Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("editText1",editText1.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

/// In second activity//

```
String passWord = getIntent().getExtras().getString("editText1");
Log.d("password : ",passWord);
```